# Responsiveness - iPad in Chrome vs iPad in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, wordpress, ipad, responsive-design

I am developing a website in a Windows system. I have Firefox and Chrome browsers installed. When I checked the responsiveness of my webpage by setting the device as iPad(768 X 1024) using 'inspect element' feature in these browsers, I could get different resultant UI for same device. Why is it so? On which browser can I rely on as I don't have any Mac/Apple devices with me to test? I am concerned of using other online web tools due to security issues. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for checking responsiveness called browserstack. You can try it from here: https://www.browserstack.com. They're offering free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no real substitute for device testing. Companies like BrowserStack offer real remote device testing but at a cost. With regard to browsers rendering differently, this has always been a pain. Look at CSS resets.